# Netbeans 7.4 with PhoneGap and iOs

Tags: ios, netbeans, cordova

I created a new PhoneGap project with Netbeans 7.4
and I tried to run the ios simulator

in iOS simulator has created an icon. clicking it opens for a few seconds, the splash of the application and then closes

the console of the mac I can see this log

```
backboardd[30110]: The 'com.coolappz.barno' bundle at (null) does not have an executable path. Please check the bundle's Info.plist file.
```

i try to: 
- new project 
- Reset Content and Settings ios Simulator

i use phonegap-2.9.0 SDK

for now i haven't Provisioning Profile

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans 7.4 does not support phonegap. It supports cordova 3.0+